# jQuery is not working on Joomla site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, joomla

I need an `imageflip` to `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` on a Joomla 2.5.19 site. I animated the `fadeIn()` and the `imageflip` with jQuery. Strange things are happening on my Joomla site.

The template comes with jQuery, nevertheless I installed  jQuery easy [jQuery easy](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327) since there are several jQuery versions loaded in the template (dont know why). 
Strangely, the `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` effect works on two mapped areas in my imagemap (far on the right, the green and the blue one which are highlighted [MySite](http://fonag.org.ec/inicio/material-didadico.html)), but not on the others.
Testing the imageflip on my computer, offline, it donly works for the same two areas. BUT, testing it in JSFiddle, it works (the [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/tv69ttbd/) switch on the left hand side from `PureJS` to any jQuery version if necessary).

I guess, something must be messed up with the jQuery?! But then again, why do two `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` work on my site and on my computer, but not the others?!

Comment: I'm not too sure what the results are supposed to be as your JSFiddle doesn't work. on a side note, update your Joomla site to v2.5.27 and your jQuery to v1.11.1

Comment: @Lodder you want to turn on jQuery on the left hand side where stands "Pure JS"

Comment: No, it doesn't. You haven't imported jQuery correctly. remove the `<src>` tag you added and import it using the Fiddle options on the left.

Comment: @Lodder that was messed up, I am sorry about that. I fixed the link! The code in the Fiddel is the code I have on my page aswell

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon,

If you have some problems using JQuery maybe you could install "JQuery Easy Plugin", that could answer your problem.

Regards.

Comment: And inside that plugin you can choose which pages enable or disable it. That should work.